# Filter through JSON data to create a job location filter and pass params to URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to build a filter for the project I'm building. I want to parse through the JSON I'm getting from the backend API, filter out the job posts based on the "location" and display it. First time creating such a filter and I'm not sure what did I do wrong here!

```
    useEffect(async () => {
    let condition = await getJobs();
    switch (jobCondition) {
      case 'On-site': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'in_person');
        break;
      case 'Remote': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'remote');
        break;
      case 'Hybrid': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'hybrid');
        break;
      default:
        condition = null;
    }
    if (condition != null) {
      const params = new URLSearchParams({
        jobs: jobFilter || null,
        location: locationFilter || null,
        since: datePosted || null,
        conditions: `${condition.con}`,
      });
      history.push({ pathname: '/', search: `${params.toString()}` });
      return;
    }
    const params = new URLSearchParams({
      jobs: jobFilter || null,
      location: locationFilter || null,
      since: null,
      conditions: null,
    });
    history.push({ pathname: '/', search: `${params.toString()}` });
  }, [jobCondition]);
```

Comment: First off, you can't use `async` in useEffect like that. Look here for some examples. Then we can move further into your issues. https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect

Comment: That was very useful, thanks, man! @JoelHager

``const fetchLocationData = async () => {
    const data = await getJobs();
    return data.json();
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    let condition = fetchLocationData();
    switch (jobCondition) {
      case 'On-site': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'in_person');
        break;
      case 'Remote': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'remote');
        break;
      case 'Hybrid': condition.filter((con) => con.jobLocation === 'hybrid');
        break;
      default:
        condition = null;
    } ``